# Prove that a given point lies between two lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

How do I check that a point lies in the region of the acute angle between two intersecting lines?

For example, how do I prove that the point $(2,4)$ lies in between the lines:

$$x - y + 3=0$$
$$x - 2y + 4=0$$

I tried to plot the lines and the point on a graph, and I can confirm the result by graphing:

[image]

But I want a method that can be used in an exam as it takes a lot of time to do.

Comment: Do you know inequalities? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Yah I know inequalities. I tried to plot the the lines and the point in the graph. But these cannot be used in exam as it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Based on the OP's comment, I have added some context in for the OP so that the question has enough context. I think this question deserves to be reopened after the new edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to plot the graph.

The point where the two lines meet is $(-2,1)$ by elimination. Since $(2,4)$ has a greater $x$-coordinate than $(-2,1)$, the region you are looking for is $x - y + 3 > 0$, $x-2y+4 < 0$ (a quick, generic sketch helps).

Therefore you just need to substitute $(2,4)$ into the inequalities and check if they are true.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @TobyMak shouldn't it be $x-y+3>0$ and $x-2y+4<0$?

Comment: Yep, thanks for the correction.